# Deleting all text from ### using a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, sql-update

i have hundreds of records in a table like this

**some text**  ### some other text

i want to delete everything after ### including ### so that only

**some text** will remain 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE some_table
SET some_column = SUBSTR( some_column, 1, Locate( '###', some_column ))
WHERE some_column LIKE '%###%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of sql you are using, being dependant on the actual database, but it would be something like this:

```
update table set textfield =     substring(textfield,0,indexof(textfield,'###'));
```

You might have to add/subtract one from the indexof result.

To test it, you can use the substring in a select:

```
select substring(textfield,0,indexof(textfield,'###')
from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '###', 1)
    WHERE col LIKE '%###%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query,it works fine

> UPDATE tablename SET columnname =
>   LEFT(columnname,locate('#',columnname) - 1) WHERE
>   locate('#',columnname) > 0